# How to create a pivot query together with group by statement with multiple columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

In order to achieve the following structure, using "pivot" table and "group by" with multiple columns.  (i.e. as illustrated in the second image below),

what would be the SQL implementation?

The source query is:

```
SELECT 
  t1.date, 
  t1.area, 
  t1.canal,
  SUM(t1.peso) AS peso
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

and source query generates a initial structure as in:

[image]

Then, the goal's to achieve a final structure grouped by columns "area" and "canal",  pivoting column "date" but only to the column "peso".

Plus, a partial total of each area, named as "total" .

As illustrated in the image bellow.

[image]

Comment: Why is sample data for Area and Canal not same in both datasets? Producing the TOTAL row for each group would be difficult if not impossible. Add tag for your database platform.

Comment: You're right. The picture was an example to illustrate the final structure, which I'm trying to achieve. The data for Area and canal can be anything, as long as they repeat in order apply group by statement properly.

Comment: You're right. The picture was an example to illustrate the final structure, which I'm trying to achieve. The data for Area and canal can be anything, as long as they repeat in order apply group by statement properly.
So, area values can be: area1, area2, area3, area13, area56, GEO CO, etc
and canal values can be: smart, rasp, drone,  can1, can2, can3, independente, moderno, C&C, etc.
Attention to the fourth row: it's the sum of canal data: first, second and third  previous rows, of each grouped area

Comment: The way I would do this is to build a report and use it Sorting & Grouping features with Sum() aggregate function to do Total calc in group header or footer. It is possible to build a stable report based on a CROSSTAB. Review http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html.

Comment: I do believe Crosstab would be the way to go. The challenge is grouping by multiple columns, using crosstab. Plus, in my scenario there are partial totals for every date and area groups.  
In the example you shared, grouping was applied only by one column (i.e. country).

Answer (score 0):

After a 24 long hours and quick nap. I finally got an asnwer.
A simple and straight forward line, using PySpark.

```
df = dfa.groupBy("area", "canal").pivot("date").sum("peso")
```

Thanks to @andrew-svds and his Warmup github's repository
https://github.com/andrew-svds/spark-pivot-examples/tree/master/0-Warmup

The complete chunk is described bellow, for reference purposes

```
qry = """
SELECT 
  t1.date, 
  t1.area, 
  t1.canal,
  t1.peso
FROM table1 t1
'''' 

dfy = spark.sql(qry)
dfy = dfa.groupBy("area", "canal").pivot("date").sum("peso")
dfy = dfy.orderBy("area", "canal")
display(dfy)
```

I believe there are many way to get the same results. That one was the simplest and more intuitive that I was able to write.

Perhaps tomorrow with a nice and good sleep, I'll get an even simpler line of code! :)

Bets wishes,
I

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).